# Get MySQL Data Using Python. But Why Does Python Corrupt The Data?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working on a new project. I want to connect the database, download the file from here and upload it again after making changes. But there is a problem. When I pull the data with Python, the result should be exactly the same. However, when I open the file, I see that the spaces are removed, adds parentheses to the beginning and end, the UTF-8 structure is broken, and the lines are completely removed. Why is this happening and how can it be resolved?

My Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f = open('sonuc.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(host='host',user='usr',password='ps',db='db',)

mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute('SELECT message FROM mybb_posts WHERE pid=1;')
sonuc = mycursor.fetchall()
f.write(str(sonuc))
f.close()
```

The original data is as follows:

```
Lets Try This!
Line 2
Line 3
Try other charecter:
like "ş", "i", "ü", "ğ", "İ"
Line 6
```

Python result (sonuc.txt):

```
(('Lets Try This!\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3\r\nTry other charecter:\r\nlike "?", "i", "ü", "?", "?"\r\nLine 6\r\n',),)
```

**Edit:**
for UTF-8 problem, add `charset='utf8mb4',` to `MySQLdb.connect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing corrupt about that. That's just the Python representation of an 1-tuple containing an 1-tuple containing a string, since `.fetchall()` returns a tuple of tuples with the columns you requested.

If you want to write the first column of each row returned by your query,

```
for row in mycursor:
    message = row[0]
    f.write(message)
f.close()
```

While you're at it, you should practice proper `open` hygiene:

```
import MySQLdb

with MySQLdb.connect(
    host="host",
    user="usr",
    password="ps",
    db="db",
) as db:
    mycursor = db.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT message FROM mybb_posts WHERE pid=1;")
    with open("sonuc.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for row in mycursor:
            message = row[0]
            f.write(message)
```